# Fatal error about NSBundle.h

Tags: ios, ios8

I am getting fatal error like below:

```
fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-cmhnsmgdfdaulbchdzoottkobtky/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Pods-Reachability-prefix-aqankredstszyhgoombnyvjatenf/Pods-Reachability-prefix.pch.pch' was built
```

I cleaned derived data but nothing has changed. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you search?  I'm sure this has been asked more than once.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't find anything

Comment: I've just used [this search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow.com:+'has+been+modified+since+the+precompiled+header') and out popped lots of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I've had this happen on occasion. Simply cleaning the build folder (command-option-shift-K) doesn't work always. The problem, in this case, is that it's a CocoaPod pch file which seems to actually live somewhere in ~/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache. The easiest thing to do is simply nuke everything in ~/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and Build after that.